# Singleton shared service in hybrid angular1 and angular2 app

Tags: angularjs, angular, typescript

Is it possible to have a singleton Angular2 service in a hybrid angular app?

It creates a different instance once my service is `upgradeAdapter.downgradeNg2Provider(Ng2Service )` even when I have `providers: [ Ng2Service ]` in the top `NgModule`:

**Angular2 Service:**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

@Injectable()
export class Ng2Service {

    private value: any;

    constructor() {
        console.log('constructor Ng2Service!');
    }

    setValue(value: any): void {
        this.value= value;
    }

    getValue(): any {
        return this.value;
    }
}
```

The service is injected to Angular1 and it works, however the **'constructor Ng2Service!'** its called two times, and when using the dummy method `setValue` from Angular1 and then try to `getValue` from Angular2 the value is **null**, however calling `getValue` from Angular1 returns the correct value.